# Can I use lirc using the i/r on my rtl2832U dongle as regular or separate i/r port?

Tags: linux, devices, hardware

Although this might have an rtlsdr tone to it, I am on a hunt for info, tip, tricks & mods related to lirc while trying to get it (or some kind of version) to work on my Linux machine.

Ultimately (for a start) I would like to see information from i/r devices (ie: different remote controls) around my house. However, if the answer to the question asked is "no, it is not possible," I wonder if anyone here knows (generally - from a UNIX & Linux point of view) if it can be accomplished simply by using the rtl dongle or if there is any other way using electronic scraps (ie: i/r receiver taken from old dvd player, cp2102 serial-usb, wiimote receiver) without having to go and buy some specialized device for it?